Tests broken for IntelliJ Spring Service after updating dependencies - legacy code
I have a legacy Spring Service that I am trying to update to remove a log4j vulnerability.
I have updated the relevant dependencies/code and my project builds, compiles and runs successfully.
However my unit tests are broken and I can't seem to find the cause.
This is the error message I get from my tests:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.softqware.company.repository.BasicTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.132 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(com.softqware.company.repository.BasicTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:990)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:593)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:515)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:484)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:430)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:411)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.JaxbAppInsightsConfigurationBuilder.build(JaxbAppInsightsConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.initialize(TelemetryConfigurationFactory.java:125)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration.getActive(TelemetryConfiguration.java:71)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient.<init>(TelemetryClient.java:86)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.common.LogTelemetryClientProxy.<init>(LogTelemetryClientProxy.java:72)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender.start(ApplicationInsightsAppender.java:83)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.AppenderModelHandler.postHandle(AppenderModelHandler.java:84)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:257)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.secondPhaseTraverse(DefaultProcessor.java:253)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.traversalLoop(DefaultProcessor.java:90)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.DefaultProcessor.process(DefaultProcessor.java:106)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.processModel(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:208)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:170)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:122)
  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericXMLConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericXMLConfigurator.java:65)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configureByResource(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:68)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.DefaultJoranConfigurator.configure(DefaultJoranConfigurator.java:35)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.invokeConfigure(ContextInitializer.java:128)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:103)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:66)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initializeLoggerContext(LogbackServiceProvider.java:52)
  at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider.initialize(LogbackServiceProvider.java:41)
  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:152)
  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:139)
  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getProvider(LoggerFactory.java:421)
  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:407)
  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:356)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
  at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:96)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
  at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
  at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
  at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
  at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
  at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
  at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
  at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1a8a8f7c
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Unknown Source)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:40)
  at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
  ... 61 more

This is what a test looks like and what I need to typically do in each test.
From what I can tell, it gives me the above error whenever I include the "@RunWith..." tag. Without the tag, the test can run but then all the repositories are null.
I have a BasicTest that I run that just has a simple Assert check on a set string value with the "@RunWith" tag and that gives me the above error as well.
package com.softqware.company.repository;

import com.github.dozermapper.core.Mapper;
import com.softqware.company.configuration.PersistenceConfiguration;
import com.softqware.company.configuration.SecurityConfiguration;
import com.softqware.company.configuration.ServiceConfiguration;
import com.softqware.company.domain.Task;
import com.softqware.company.domain.User;
import com.softqware.company.domain.enumeration.AssetReviewStatus;
import com.softqware.company.service.TaskService;
import com.softqware.company.web.dto.console.ConsoleTaskDetailsDto;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Rollback;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceConfiguration.class, PersistenceConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class AssetReviewStatusTest {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AssetReviewStatusTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Mapper dozerBeanMapper;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    private final static int TEST_USER_ID = 4682;
    private final static int TASK_ID = 186762;

    @Test
    public void testGetTaskCheckAssetReviewStatus() {

        //Make sure values have correct numbers
        assertEquals(AssetReviewStatus.getValueFromOrdinal(0), AssetReviewStatus.NOT_NOTIFIED);
        assertEquals(AssetReviewStatus.getValueFromOrdinal(1), AssetReviewStatus.NOTIFIED);
        assertEquals(AssetReviewStatus.getValueFromOrdinal(2), AssetReviewStatus.NOTIFICATION_UNDER_REVIEW);
        assertEquals(AssetReviewStatus.getValueFromOrdinal(3), AssetReviewStatus.COMPLETE);

        User user = userRepository.findOne((long) TEST_USER_ID);
        assertNotNull(user);

        //test task
        Long testTaskId = (long) TASK_ID;

        //Check task exists
        Task task = taskRepository.findOne(testTaskId);
        assertNotNull(task);

        //Check AssetReviewStatus for intial state
        AssetReviewStatus ars = task.getAssetReviewStatus();
        assertNotNull(ars);
        assertEquals(AssetReviewStatus.NOT_NOTIFIED, ars);

    }

}

Finally, here are my dependencies as included in my pom.xml.
There are going to be some very old versions, like I said, it's legacy software. But it currently works and the tests also need to work.
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Database connection (hibernate, apache commons pooling, db connector) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.30.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QueryDSL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Dozer Mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Velocity Template -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Http Components -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Http Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Quartz Scheduler -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application Insights-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-web-auto</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- API, java.xml.bind module -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>company</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                <!-- include any other file types you want to filter -->
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>


If I missed any information required to help, please let me know. I think everything relevant so far is included.
I've already tried updating to use Junit5, that causes too many issues with Spring-Data dependency not being up to date and updating that dependency requires a massive load of code changes that I would rather avoid right now and could very well break the service.
I have removed the entire test directory and added it fresh with the same results once I start adding the "@RunWith" tag, trying to get my repositories available.
We are going to be moving away from this piece of legacy software but this needs to work for right now, so other code bases or overall alternatives are not an option right now.

It tells you what the error is in the call stack. You'd need to add --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED to your JVM options whenever you run the unit tests and the possibly the code (and you'll probably have to add-opens for 5 or 6 more packages as well). You'll need to add this, run it and see what other packages it wants open. Of course, no guarantee it'll run after you add all of them, there may be other issues, but that's what it's complaining about now. The joys of running ancient dependencies :).

Thank you for your response. I will give that a try. I am a little lost how you got the that package in particular though. I don't see any mention of it being required in the stacktrace and if it's going to need others it would be helpful to know how you spotted this. Thanks once again.

From the stack trace you posted:
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @1a8a8f7c.
If you mean how it gets mapped to jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util, shrug. Just tribal knowledge that's posted on the internet lol. I never looked into why it gets mapped like that.

If it complains about java.file next, it gets mapped the same way to --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED, etc. I've noticed in my experience, that you generally need to add the util, file, tree, api and code ones. But sometimes you don't need all of them.

Yes, how it gets mapped is what I wanted to know, I had no luck when searching for that error myself.
Thank you for your help, I think I see the relation between them a bit more now so hopefully if more come up I can put 2 and 2 together and it all works in the end.

Please use an old JDK (JDK 8) to compile and execute it. Do not use the latest JDK. Does Spring Version 4.3.20 work with Java 11? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743146/does-spring-version-4-3-20-work-with-java-11) , One answer mentioned:
"JDK Version Range:

Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10
Spring Framework 4.3.x: JDK 6-8"


Adding the '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED' to my vmoptions file does not seem to have worked. I believe it's been put in the right place, Help->Edit Custom VM Options... this opens the idea64.exe.vmoptions file where I placed your suggested code.

This service has been successfully running and hosted on it's current JDK/Java, and our tests have been running fine as well with said versions until I updated a handfull of packages to remove the log4j vulnerability.
